# Cancel pending intent with FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I have set a `PendingIntent` with `UPDATE_CURRENT_FLAG`, when i cancelled it, i try to check `PendingIntent` instance (current pending intent) with `FLAG_NO_CREATE` flag, but the result doesn't return null, please tell me how to fix it. Thank You

Comment: Post some code, how did you implement canceling and the check

Comment: Please show us the code you are using the cancel the `PendingIntent`.

Comment: Sorry to say but the issue has solve, i use UPDATE_CURRENT_FLAG when create alarm manager, and add a flag in intent that i used, so i can update the pending intent without i cancel it. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Wonderful. Please answer your own question and accept that answer, so that others can benefit from your solution!